# error '80020009' - But I'm not in a query

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I have a system that places an order in ASP, and when an order is submitted, a notification email goes out.

When I submit the order, I get error '80020009' and the line it points to is this:

```
email_text = email_text & "<html>" & _
```

That's a simple line that just starts building the html string that fills the email! Isn't error '80020009' supposed to be for SQL statements? Or am I missing something?

The page still continues on and completes the order process, it just shows that error message first.

I realize this question doesn't really provide much detail, but I don't know what else to specify, I'm just at a loss.

EDIT: Here's some SQL that is a few lines up from that line. Not sure how this would cause the issue, since it's telling me it's on that email line, but it can't hurt to throw it in:

```
str = "SELECT creation_date, supplier FROM argus.PURCHASE_ORDER WHERE purchase_order = '" & Trim(Request.Form("order_id")) & "' AND customer = '" & Session("customer_id") & "' AND store = '" & Session("store_id") & "' AND userid = '" & Session("user_id") & "'"
            Set rst = ConnFW.Execute(str)
            str2 = "SELECT a.store_name, a.address1, a.address2, a.city, a.state_cd, a.zipcode, b.customer_name, c.supplier_account FROM argus.STORE a, argus.CUSTOMER b, argus.ELIGIBLE_SUPPLIER c WHERE a.customer = b.customer AND a.customer = c.customer AND a.store = " & Session("store_id") & " AND b.customer = " & Session("customer_id") & " AND c.supplier = " & Trim(rst("supplier")) & ""
            Set rst2 = ConnFW.Execute(str2)
```

Comment: For reference: [Why do I get 80020009 errors?](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-i-get-80020009-errors.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you provide additional code?  There isn't anything wrong with your code except you need to make sure you have something on the line following the underscore:

```
email_text = email_text + "<html>" & _
               ""
```

-- EDIT

Thanks for posting your edits.  I see a couple potential issues.  In your second recordset object, your trying to access `rst("supplier")`, but that field hasn't been read yet.  Instead of using `connfw.execute(str)` which is used to execute sql statements like `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`, use `rst.open` which is used with `SELECT`.

Try something like:

```
supplier = ""

rst.open str, connfw

if not rst.eof then
   supplier = rst("supplier")
end if

rst.close
```

Then use supplier in your 2nd sql statement.  Also, if the supplier field from the eligible_supplier table is a string, you need to wrap single quotes around that field in your where clause.

Comment: It's a very large file, but a few lines above that there is a SQL query. I'll post that too, I'm just not sure why it would tell me the error was on that line...

Comment: Thanks for editing your question.  See my edits above.  Good luck.

Comment: I tried adding that (and did a similar change to all my earlier queries in that file). It still runs, but I'm still getting the error on that random line for some reason. Seems to have a problem with email_text. Thanks for your effort though, I appreciate it.